# Divide a value in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview,in the gridview i have a button called as yes..when i click this button the Total amount textbox should be divided by 2 and the answer should be displayed in the same textbox..I have created an event called as divide...but I dont know how to code further..Please can someone help me.. Below is my code

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gridview2" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="4" CssClass="vutblrow" 
    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" HeaderStyle-CssClass="vutblhdr" 
    Height="16px" onrowcreated="Gridview2_RowCreated" 
    onrowdatabound="grvCalc_RowDataBound" PagerStyle-Mode="NumericPages" 
    ShowFooter="true" TabIndex="3" Width="1%">
    <PagerStyle BorderStyle="Solid" CssClass="pgr" Height="25px" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Serial Number" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="From Place">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Textfrom" runat="server" CssClass="txtBoxNormalmedium"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="To Place">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Textto" runat="server" 
CssClass="txtBoxNormalmedium"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Distance Travelled (kms)">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxdist" runat="server" CssClass="txtBoxNormalmedium"></asp:TextBox>
                 </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount Paid (per km)">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxamt" runat="server" CssClass="txtBoxNormalmedium"></asp:TextBox>
                   </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Conveyance Shared?">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnyes" Text="Yes" runat="server" CssClass="btnNormal" OnClick="divide" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total amount">
               <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtboxtotal" runat="server" 
                        CssClass="txtBoxNormalmedium"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbltotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd1" runat="server" CssClass="btnNormalAdd" OnClick="add" Text="Add New Row" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnok3" runat="server" CssClass="btnNormalAdd" OnClick="ok_click" Text="OK" />
                 </FooterTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
              <asp:TemplateField>
                   <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CssClass="lnkbut" OnClick="LinkButton2_Click">Remove</asp:LinkButton>
                   </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
          </Columns>
     </asp:GridView>


    protected void divide(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
```

Comment: This is just the client-side markup, do you already have some code behind written for this? Or are you planning in doing it using JavaScript?

Comment: I want to write the code in C#...unfortunately i dont know how to do so

Comment: Unless you are okay with a postback, I would highly recommend using some scripting on the page.  Make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this

Set CommandName as 'select' for the Button btnyes
Add OnSelectedIndexChangedevent to gridview
Clicking the btnyes will trigger OnSelectedIndexChangedevent event of the GeidView.
```

```
protected void Gridview2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtboxtotal = (TextBox)Gridview2.SelectedRow.FindControl("txtboxtotal");
    txtboxtotal.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(txtboxtotal.Text) / 2).ToString();
}
```